# Why Task.WhenAll requires a manually created Task to be started when the same doesn't require for async methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Ex, the following code manually instantiates a Task and passes to a `Task.WhenAll` in a `List<T>`

```
public async Task Do3()
{
    var task1 = new Task(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); Console.WriteLine("########## task1"); });

    var taskList = new List<Task>() { task1};

    taskList[0].Start();

    var taskDone = Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    await taskDone;
}
```

without starting the Task it doesn't work, it hangs forever calling from a console app, but the below works just fine without starting it

```
public async Task Do3()
{
    //var task1 = new Task(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); Console.WriteLine("########## task1"); });

    var taskList = new List<Task>() { SubDo1() };

    //taskList[0].Start();

    var taskDone = Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    await taskDone;
}

public async Task SubDo1()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("########## task1");
}
```

Comment: `SubDo1` returns already started task. Almost everything returns started task, not yet started task is a very rare beast.

Comment: [Don't use `Task` constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html), especially not with an asynchronous delegate.

Comment: [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#task-status) state that if method returns a `Task` it should be started: _"If a TAP method internally uses a task's constructor to instantiate the task to be returned, the TAP method must call Start on the Task object before returning it."_

Comment: Are you asking why the Microsoft engineers took the decision that async methods should return running tasks, and the `Task` constructor should return non-running tasks? Are you interested in the rationale behind these decisions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task` is used in two completely different ways here; when you call an `async` method: *you are starting it yourself*; at this point, two things can happen:

1. it can run to completion (eventually) without ever reaching a truly asynchronous state, and return a completed (or faulted) task to the caller
2. it can reach an incomplete awaitable (in this case `await Task.Delay`), at which point it creates a state machine that represents the current position, schedules a completion operation on that incomplete awaitable (to do whatever comes next), and then returns an *incomplete* task to the caller

It is not "not started"; to return *anything* to the caller: we have started it. However, unlike `Task.Start()`, we start that work on *our current thread* - not an external worker thread - with other threads only getting involved based on how that incomplete awaitable schedules the completion callbacks that the compiler gives it.

This is **very** different to the `new Task(...)` scenario, where nothing is initially started. That's why they behave differently. Note also the Remarks section of the [`Task` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor) here - it is a very niche API, and honestly: not hugely recommended.

Additionally: when you don't immediately `await` an `async` method, you're *essentially* going into concurrent territory (assuming the awaitable won't always complete synchronously). In some cases, this matters, and may cause threading problems re race-conditions. It shouldn't matter much in this case, though.

Comment: I have so many follow up questions, let me start with the most obvious one for me: A) I know Task.Run run in a different thread(s). but I coudn't find reference that is the case for taskInstance.Start() I assumed it runs on the same thread just like calling an async method.

Comment: @AmandaSai98b [Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) says "scheduling it for execution to the current TaskScheduler."; it isn't obvious, but the .ctor uses the default scheduler here, which [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) says: it uses the thread-pool - ultimately, if you wanted to start a method on the current thread, you'd... just call the method

Comment: wouldn't calling an async method also run under the current TaskScheduler as well?

Comment: @AmandaSai98b no; if you call an async method *directly*, then the sequence of events is as I discussed above, with possible outcomes 1 and 2; calling an async method doesn't do *anything* re threads - at all; it is only the `await` on an incomplete downstream awaitable that has any say on threading